# How can I reset ta.valuwhen in pinescript?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I have a simple strategy that goes long after a divergence condition is met but it doesn't reset that divergence condition and keeps going long. How do I reset it to zero once it is met?

```
    longCondition = ta.valuewhen(pos_reg_div_detected,close,1) and close > close[1]
if (longCondition)
    strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long)

shortCondition = ta.valuewhen(neg_reg_div_detected,close,1) and close < close[1]
if (shortCondition)
    strategy.entry("Short", strategy.short)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can detect the change and assign a value to a variable using the `ta.change()` and `:=` reassignment operator and reset it back to `0` on every ba:

```
float valueWhen = ta.valuewhen(pos_reg_div_detected,close,1)
float valueWhenOrZero = 0 // resets to zero at each iteration.

if ta.change(valueWhen)
    valueWhenOrZero := valueWhen // assign a value only when a change event occurs.

plot(valueWhen)
plot(valueWhenOrZero)
```

Comment: How would I implement this in my strategy.entry condition?

Comment: You can replace valueWhen with your longCondition to achieve the same result.